# How to calculate the truth table answers in java?

Tags: java, graph

I want to find  regions using truth table.

[image: graph pic]

[image: truth table]

But , I have some doubts.

- How can I calculate the x>2 is NO ?
- How can I calculate the x>2 is YES ?
- How can I find the regions using this truth table ?

I want to print using if statement like this

```
if(?){
  System.out.println("Region F");
}
```

How can I calculate this truth table in java ?

Comment: Can you explain what a exactly a *region* is and how you would compute it by hand?

Comment: I added my graph pic in question.

Comment: What have you tried? I assume this is some sort of (home)work. You learn more from at least trying yourself, instead of immediately delegating the heavy lifting to other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using nested if statements:

```
boolean cond1 = x > 0;
boolean cond2 = y > 0;
boolean cond3 = Math.abs(x) > 2 * Math.abs(y);
boolean cond4 = Math.abs(y) > 2 * Math.abs(x);
if (cond1) {
  if (cond2) {
    if (cond3) {
      if (cond4) {
        return "!";
      } else {
        return "C";
    } else {
      if (cond4) {
        return "A";
      else {
        return "B";
      }
    }
  } else {
    // ... repeat the same pattern
  }
} else {
  // ... repeat the same pattern
}
```

---

Or, using a literal translation of the truth table:

```
boolean cond1 = x > 0;
boolean cond2 = y > 0;
boolean cond3 = Math.abs(x) > 2 * Math.abs(y);
boolean cond4 = Math.abs(y) > 2 * Math.abs(x);

if        (cond1 && cond2 && cond3 && cond4) {
  return "!";
} else if (cond1 && cond2 && cond3 && !cond4) {
  return "C";
} else if (cond1 && cond2 && !cond3 && cond4) {
  return "A";
} else if (cond1 && cond2 && !cond3 && !cond4) {
  return "B";
} else if (cond1 && !cond2 && cond3 && cond4) {
...
```

Comment: Can you explain in detail ?

Comment: @Poorvaja What else is there to explain? This is the most straightforward possible 'transcription' of a truth table into code: starting from the bottom of the truth table, we ask "What if all four conditions are true?" then "what if the first three are true but the last one is false?" then "what if 1, 2, and 4 are true but 3 is false?" and so on. We use nested if statements to cut down on repetition slightly.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this to start:

```
if (x > 0) {
    if (y > 0) {

    } ...
} else {
    if (y > 0) {

    } ...
}
```

Comment: I confused. Can you explain in detail ?

Answer (score 0):

You can’t ‘calculate’ this because you don’t change the value. Instead you need to compare two values. Therefor you can use if and else statements. If you are not familiar with them you need to learn basic Java.

In your case you could use Math.abs(x) to get the absolute value of x and ‘&&’ as AND to require multiple statements.

So a simple way to create your statement could look like this:

```
if (x > 0 && y > 0 && Math.abs(x) > 2*Math.abs(y) && Math.abs(y) > 2*Math.abs(x)) {
    //the region is !
} else if (…) {
```

Edit:

| Placeholder | Your condition | Java condition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | x > 0 | `x > 0` |
| b | y > 0 | `y > 0` |
| c | IxI > 2IyI | `Math.abs(x) > 2*Math.abs(y)` |
| d | IyI > 2IxI | `Math.abs(y) > 2*Math.abs(x)` |

Use ! to negate a condition. So if x > 0 is No use !x > 0. To combine this conditions set the Java condition in my Placeholder.

The given example above is:

```
if (a && b && c && d) { //Region !
```

So your first line (No, No, No, No) would look like:

```
if (!a && !b && !c && !d) { //Region F
```

And the next three look like:

```
} else if (!a && !b && !c && d) { //Region E
} else if (!a && !b && c && !d) { //Region G
} else if (!a && !b && c && d) { //Region !
```

Another example:

```
} else if (a && b && !c && !d) { //Region B
```

Note: This is not an efficient way to do it especially if you upscale a lot but it seems like an easy way based on your knowledge.

Comment: Can you give an example for another one region ?